# proving fractional Helly's theorem for boxes and rectangles

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, combinatorial-geometry, rectangles

I'm having a hard time proving the followings. the background: I'm self-learning combinatorial geometry based on 'lectures on Discrete Geometry' by Matousek:

> Q1.Let B be a finite family of axis-parallel boxes in $R^{d}$ such that any two have a non empty intersection. prove that they all have a non empty intersection.
>
> Q2. Let R be a finite collection of axis parallel rectangles in $R^{2}$ such that out of any three, there are some two that have a non-empty intersection.Prove that the rectangles in R can be stabbed by 3 points and show that the number 3 is the best here.

I know the proofs are based on Helly's Theorem\  Fractional Helly's Theorem , but wasn't able to make progress.

Any proofs, hints, leads , thoughts would be much appreciated  !

Answer (score 0):

Question $1$ is quite easy. Just project the family of boxes onto each of the $d$ dimensions & apply Helly's theorem for each of these $1$ dimensional cases. Then the product of each of these $1$ dimensional intersections will intersect each of the boxes.

Not sure how to do Q$2$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I figured out that I should project but did not succeeded in formulating it mathematically. How would you formulate it? TIA
And BTW I was not able to solve Q2 at all

Comment: should it be proofed by induction?

Comment: Yes, you could use induction.